# What is the best way to build android App selecting some activities, given that i have 5 activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Say I have 5 activities with 2 templates each. (You can assume that there is a button in each activity linked to other).
Let us call them 1A,1B; 2A,@B; ... 5A,5B.
Now based on some input (Say A, B, A, A, B), I've to compile App using activities & linking like 1A->2B->3A->4A->5B.
You can assume there is a button in activity X on which activity X+1 should be activated.

The issue i am facing is, how to handle linking here. Should I create OnClick function in every activity by editing the code via some script, or there is a better way to do it?

Comment: You should write what techinques you have tried, but basically what you will eventually want to do is start activity with an intent from another activity.

Comment: It is intents that trigger an activity to become visible on the screen. Why don't you have correspondence between "some input" and intents( explicit intents )? It is pretty much straight forward!

Comment: Sorry for incomplete question. Edited the question.
Arslan, Even if i have map of input & intent, i want only those specific activities to be part of code & not others. Basically, on mentioned input, App should only contain specific 5 activities linked.